# why am I getting this syntax error

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
if(gasType.Items.Add("3.19") == checked)
{
}
```

I keep getting a Syntax error stating that I am missing ( anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is gasType?  What is the exact error message?  Is it the only syntax error you get? What is checked?

Comment: what is the syntax error also please paste more of your code.. also what are you trying to check.. is this a checkbox or ListItem..?? what..?

Comment: Can you say more about what is gasType, for example ? check the parameter type of your add method ?

Comment: What is the type of `gasType` and what is `checked`?

Answer (score 6):

`checked` is a keyword - you can't declare an identifier called that. You should have an error at the point of its declaration, too.

The reason you're getting that particular error is that it's expecting a checked expression, e.g.

```
if (gasType.Items.Add("3.19") == checked(y + 1 == 20))
```

If you *really* want to use the name `checked`, you could prefix it with `@` like this:

```
bool @checked = true;

if (gasType.Items.Add("3.19") == @checked)
```

I wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: Thanks that helped it was for a drop down list.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but checked is a keyword in C#

Answer (score 0):

The Add() method doesn't return a value and your trying to compare it.

Comment: `HashSet<T>.Add` does, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If the item is a list of any sort, the Add() method doesn't return the object added. So, what you're really saying is if(  == checked).

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking to do with this, but definitely rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is likely that if your `Items.Add()` method is a stock CLR collection (as seems likely), something like an instance of `SCG.List<T>`, the `Add()` method almost certainly returns `void`: there's nothing to compare.